# XNA vs MonoGame frame rate differences

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

I have ported my game to both XNA and MonoGame, and I noticed that in the XNA project the game, with frame rate set to 60 from the default of 30, was a lot more laggy compared to MonoGame.

I noticed this behavior on a Windows Phone 8.1 Device.

If I then set

```
timer.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

the frame rate issues disappear. How come?

Comment: If you are using the WP emulator, then know it's a known limitation/bug of it when using XAML views and XNA.

Comment: I'm debugging directly on my device (Windows Phone 8.1)